# How to remove a route which is not registered in web.php but exist at php artisan route:list

Tags: reactjs, laravel, breeze, inertiajs, laravel-breeze

I have a problem removing the route which does not exist in web.php but when I checked at PHP artisan route:list, its still appears on the list.

I'm trying to remove the route to access the default laravel breeze + react register. to replace with my own route.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return Inertia::render('Welcome', [
    'canLogin' => Route::has('login'),

]);
});

Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
   return Inertia::render('Dashboard');
})->middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->name('dashboard');

Route::group(['middleware' => ['role:Admin']], function () {
  Route::get('/new_register', 
  [\App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisteredUserController::class, 'create'])- 
  >middleware(['auth','verified'])->name('regis'); <-- my own route
});
```

this is the route list
[image]

as you can see , the route is not registered at web.php but still appear in route list

Comment: Cached? Try `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: ok let me try this

Comment: @brombeer not working

Comment: Not sure about Breeze but i _think_ there was something like `Auth::routes()` in web.php that creates all auth routes. If that doesn't exist I don't know, maybe search Laravel's/Breeze's source code?